# DB2 for windows - Stored Procedure - Printing table values at multiple points for debugging

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm new to DB2. I'm writing a procedure to use some GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE, insert and manipulate data and return it. But for debugging I need to know what the table look like after each step (similar to select in MS SQL SERVER). Is there any way to achieve this.

For example:
Insert something in to GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "ABC"

```
DECLARE CR1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR 
Select * from ABC FOR READ ONLY;
```

Manipulate some data in ABC Table

```
DECLARE CR2 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR 
Select * from ABC FOR READ ONLY;

OPEN CR1 ;

OPEN CR2 ;
```

Both CR1 and CR2 returns same values (values after manipulation)

Is there a way to print the table then and there for debugging the values in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can [print information](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0053551.html), but I would recommend using a [routine debugger as provided by IBM Data Studio](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS62YD_4.1.1/com.ibm.debug.spd.plsql.doc/topics/cbsovrv.html). There, you [set breakpoints](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS62YD_4.1.1/com.ibm.debug.spd.plsql.doc/topics/cbsbkpt.html) on the line where you want to inspect the stored procedure. During execution you can then see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks. I believe Print information might not help as I need to compare the entire table content after each step. Will check routine debugger.

Answer (score 1):

[Conditional compilation in SQL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/c0056403.html)

Example:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
SET CURRENT SQL_CCFLAGS = 'DEBUG:TRUE'@
--SET CURRENT SQL_CCFLAGS = ''@

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_DEBUG
BEGIN
  DECLARE V_ITER INT;

  DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEST (VALUE INT) WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED;
  _IF __DEBUG _THEN
    DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.DEBUG (ITER INT, VALUE INT) WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED;
  _END

  SET V_ITER=1; INSERT INTO SESSION.TEST VALUES 1,2,3;
  _IF __DEBUG _THEN
    INSERT INTO SESSION.DEBUG (ITER, VALUE) SELECT V_ITER, VALUE FROM SESSION.TEST;
  _END

  SET V_ITER=2; INSERT INTO SESSION.TEST VALUES 4,5,6;
  _IF __DEBUG _THEN
    INSERT INTO SESSION.DEBUG (ITER, VALUE) SELECT V_ITER, VALUE FROM SESSION.TEST;
  _END
END@

CALL TEST_DEBUG@
SELECT * FROM SESSION.TEST@
SELECT * FROM SESSION.DEBUG@
```

When you tested your SP, uncomment the SET CURRENT SQL_CCFLAGS = '' clause and recreate your SP.
All the _IF ... _END blocks will be removed from the compiled code in this case.